# Grunt newer is very slow

Tags: javascript, performance, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have a copy task, which copies all files (except some files in some dirs) in another directory; then files on those directories are stripped out (with grunt-strip-code).
Copy task is slow, so I tried to speed up by copying just modified files, using grunt-newer. But newer seems to be as slow as the copy itself.

This is performance measured with grunt-time without newer task:

```
Execution Time (2016-10-18 13:10:14 UTC+2)
loading tasks      849ms  ██ 1%
copy:copyApp    1m 33.7s  ████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 99%
Total 1m 34.5s
```

This is performance measured with grunt-newer, and with no change (i.e. no need to perform copy):

```
$ grunt newer:copy:copyApp
Reading build.properties

Running "newer:copy:copyApp" (newer) task
No newer files to process.

Done, without errors.

Execution Time (2016-10-18 13:33:26 UTC+2)
loading tasks          2.8s  ███████ 4%
newer:copy:copyApp  1m 6.2s  ██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 96%
Total 1m 9s
```

This is part of Gruntfile configuring copy task:

```
grunt.config('copy', {
    copyApp: {
        src: ["**", "!**/dist/**", "!**/build.properties", "!**/Grunt*", "!**/node_modules/**", "!**/comp/**", "!**/package*"],
        dest: compPathNtvApp
    }
} );
```

And this is how I use grunt-new:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', 'newer:copy:copyApp');
```

I expected effective performance boost using grunt newer. Was I wrong, or I am making some mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

I found that main problem is due to this line:

```
    src: ["**", "!**/dist/**", "!**/build.properties", "!**/Grunt*", "!**/node_modules/**", "!**/comp/**", "!**/package*"],
```

If I use filter instead of minimatch/glob, performance greatly improves

```
$ grunt newer:copy:copyApp
Reading build.properties

Running "newer:copy:copyApp" (newer) task

Running "copy:copyApp" (copy) task
Created 1 directory

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2016-10-18 16:45:37 UTC+2)
loading tasks       650ms  ███████ 4%
newer:copy:copyApp  16.2s  ██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 96%
Total 16.9s
```